# What is meant by NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 1549

Tags: cocoa, nsxmlparser, core-foundation

I am trying to parse a xml document using NSXMLParser. Every time it result in  NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 1549. I cant find any documentation regarding that error code.
Any help.
-Shakthi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a problem with resolving a DTD in the XML. Try disabling DTD downloading with this code:

```
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks a lot. BTW is theire any documentation for the error codes. Apple documents covers some 100 errors  but I couldn't find error code 1549.

Comment: I didn't find anything about 1549 either actually. I'm not sure where that error code comes from. For most errors searching the Xcode documentation is enough as there are various pages that list the standard errors.